# Docker Tutorial: Daemonized Container Closes - Syntax Error

Tags: shell, docker, syntax-error, ubuntu-14.04

I've been working through the user guide linked here:
[Docker User Guide: Containers](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/dockerizing/).
 I ran this command in the docker terminal:

```
$ docker run -d ubuntu:14.04 /bin/sh -c "while true; do echo hello world; sleep 1; done"
```

This is supposed to create a container that runs in the background. However, when I look and see if it is running, using:

```
$ docker ps -a
```

It shows that the container was created but has stopped running.
The log of the container contains the following:

```
true;: 1: true;: Syntax error: end of file unexpected
```

Running a command without trying to create a daemon yields a similar result:

```
$  docker run ubuntu:14.04 /bin/sh -c "while true; do echo hello world; sleep 1; done"
true;: 1: true;: Syntax error: end of file unexpected
```

I'm guessing there is a syntax error in my script, but I'm not seeing it. Any suggestions are appreciated.

([This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29957653/docker-container-not-starting-docker-start) question is somewhat similar, and may be relevant).

EDIT Some additional information: I'm running Docker in Windows 7, using the Docker Quickstart Terminal

EDIT2 The accepted answer below worked for me, except I had to append "default" to a number of the commands, to specify I was talking to the default machine.

Comment: Have you tried running it in an actual system shell rather than in whatever the docker terminal is? This is what you'd get if the command was run from something that doesn't preserve or understand word boundaries.

Comment: @thatotherguy I don't think "docker terminal" is a thing. But I think I recall seeing similar issues with commands passed to docker and the "parsing" being stupid.

Comment: What version of docker are you using? What shell are you using?

Comment: I am using docker version 1.9.1. I'm not entirely sure what "shell" means, but I'm using the Docker Quickstart Terminal if that's of any help.

Comment: What OS are you on? Are you using a VM?

Comment: I'm running Docker in Windows 7, not inside a virtual machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with single quotes instead:

```
docker run -d ubuntu:14.04 /bin/sh -c 'while true; do echo hello world; sleep 1; done'
```

Note: as [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34782572/6309):

> When I try to use VirtualBox's console there is all fine.
>
> But it always fail in windows's console (using Docker Quickstart Terminal).
>
> I think the problem is about the end-of-line code (`\n`,`\r` or `\r\n`).

So try to ssh to the docker machine first (`docker-machine ssh $(docker-machine ip <machine_name>)`), and then try again.

For a recent docker-machine, which creates the machine '`default`', you don't even have to type anything (here I use `dm` as an alias to `docker-machine`):

[image: dm ssh]

Then the command works with single or double quotes:

[image: single quotes]

Comment: funny thing, both `docker run -d ubuntu:14.04 /bin/sh -c ' sleep infinity' ` and `docker run -d ubuntu:14.04 /bin/sh -c " sleep infinity"` work fine, so maybe the shorter form is better, as we do not have to care about single quotes or not

Comment: I have not tried the ssh stuff yet. However, the command with single quotes gives the same error message as before.

Comment: @user30632 Hence my suggestion to ssh first.

Comment: I attempted the following: `$ docker-machine ssh $(docker-machine ip default)`. The output stated that the host did not exist. However, when I run `$ docker-machine ls`, the default machine is listed.

Comment: @user30632 then try docker-machine ssh <IP> using the IP listed by docker-machine ls

Comment: `$ docker-machine ls` doesn't list an IP, although `$ docker-machine ip default` does. Using this IP yields: `Host does not exist: "192.168.99.100"` which is the same error as before.

Comment: @user30632 then try first docker-machine start default

Comment: The output of starting the default machine is this: `Machine "default" is already running.`

Comment: @millsmess ok: try with its name: `docker-machine ssh <name_of_machine>`, as `docker-machine ssh default`

Comment: @millsmess I have edited the answer to add pictures, illustrating what I see on my on desktop (Windows 10 + docker-machine 0.6.0-rc1)

Comment: That worked! I have upvoted your answer and accepted it. (My upvote does not display because I do not have enough reputation).

Answer (score 0):

You're using normal user for docker build.

For shell script you should use root account.

So try:

```
sudo docker run -d ubuntu:14.04 /bin/sh -c "while true; do echo hello world; sleep 1; done"
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that I'm doing this in Windows 7, and so using sudo returns a "command not found" error..